# getimagesize() limiting file size for remote URL

Tags: php, validation, getimagesize

I could use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to validate  an image, but the problem is what if the mischievous user puts a link to a [10GB random file](http://proof.ovh.net/files/10Gio.dat) then it would whack my production server's bandwidth. How do I limit the filesize `getimagesize()` is getting? (eg. 5MB max image size)

PS: I did [research](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#87188) before asking.

Comment: Maybe this suits your use case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635936/super-fast-getimagesize-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the file separately, imposing a maximum size you wish to download:

```
function mygetimagesize($url, $max_size = -1)
{
        // create temporary file to store data from $url
        if (false === ($tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), uniqid('mgis')))) {
                return false;
        }
        // open input and output
        if (false === ($in = fopen($url, 'rb')) || false === ($out = fopen($tmpfname, 'wb'))) {
                unlink($tmpfname);
                return false;
        }
        // copy at most $max_size bytes
        stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out, $max_size);

        // close input and output file
        fclose($in); fclose($out);

        // retrieve image information
        $info = getimagesize($tmpfname);

        // get rid of temporary file
        unlink($tmpfname);

        return $info;
}
```

Comment: Hi, wouldn't I have memory issues with `stream_copy_to_stream` if I have like 100 users uploading simultaneously?

Comment: @Severus how would you imagine that? Internally it uses 8K buffers to perform the copy I believe.

Comment: @Severus could you be more specific? :)

Comment: so how will I throw an exception when the limit is reached?

Comment: @Severus stream_copy_to_stream() returns the bytes copied so you could check if the number equals $max_size

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this function *limits* to the maximum filesize? I tried using it to an image and it missed a few bytes, the quality of the image degraded.

Comment: @Severus it copies at most $max_size bytes, so if the result of the copy operation equals that number you should not continue.

Comment: @Jack: Nice answer, check out also `file_put_contents`, might make it even a bit more compact.

Comment: @hakre no, that's not possible because file_put_contents() requires the whole data to write iirc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do something like `getimagesize('http://example.com')` to begin with, since this will download the image once, check the size, then discard the downloaded image data. *That's* a real waste of bandwidth.

So, separate the download process from the checking of the image size. For example, use `fopen` to open the image URL, read little by little and write it to a temporary file, keeping count of how much you have read. Once you cross 5MB and are still not finished reading, you stop and reject the image.

You *could* try to read the HTTP Content-Size header *before* starting the actual download to weed out obviously large files, but you cannot rely on it, since it can be spoofed or omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](http://tracker.phpbb.com/browse/PHPBB3-8672), you need to make some change to fit your requirement.

```
function getimagesize_limit($url, $limit)
{
 global $phpbb_root_path;
 $tmpfilename = tempnam($phpbb_root_path . 'store/', unique_id() . '-');
  $fp = fopen($url, 'r');
 if (!$fp) return false; 
 $tmpfile = fopen($tmpfilename, 'w');
  $size = 0;
 while (!feof($fp) && $size<$limit)
 {
  $content = fread($fp, 8192);
  $size += 8192;  fwrite($tmpfile, $content);
 }
  fclose($fp);
 fclose($tmpfile);
  $is = getimagesize($tmpfilename);
 unlink($tmpfilename);
 return $is;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you add `8192`?

Comment: @Severus It's just mean read 8kb one time, no special meanings.

Comment: which file at phpbb is this implemented?