# how do I set keys for JSONObjects in PHP

Tags: php

Short description: I query my `PHP` back-end which returns rows of data from an `SQL` database, the data is returned in `JSON` format. The data includes a link to an image for each row, to be able to create a placeholder I also determine the width and height of the image by reading 32KB of image data, using the "ranger" function as per [webarto's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635936/super-fast-getimagesize-in-php) and then append this data to my resulting `JSONArray`.

This is the the code I have:

```
                    $result = $conn->query ( $sql );
                    $response = array ();
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                            /* get image url */
                            $url = $row ['image'];
                            /* get the first 32KB of image data */
                            $raw = ranger ( $url );
                            /* recreate a part of the original image */
                            $im = imagecreatefromstring ( $raw );
                            /* determine width and height of the image */
                            $width = imagesx ( $im );
                            $height = imagesy ( $im );
                            /* add width and height at the end of the array */
                            array_push ( $row, $width );
                            array_push ( $row, $height );
                            $response [] = $row;
                        }
                        $j_result = json_encode ( $response );
                        echo $j_result;
```

Which gives the following result for one row:

```
 {"lang":"de","title":"Sample Title","article":"Sample text","time":"1416070535","image":"someimage.jpg","source":"sample.com","0":606,"1":379}
```

I'm not really familiar with `PHP` and managed to append the image dimensions using the `array_push()` function. However, this gives me "0", "1" etc. as the key for those values as you can see in the `JSON` above.

**The question:** how can I set those keys so `json_encode` does not set them automatically?

Comment: [Decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json into a PHP array, modify it then [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `array_push` you can simply use the index you want directly:

```
$row['width'] = $width;
$row['height'] = $height;
```

Comment: @Droidman you didn't get my answer ? What part isn't clear, so I can try to reformulate?

Comment: I mean it's a shame I haven't managed it by myself =) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` isn't actually setting any indices of your JSON object, you are doing so in PHP. `json_encode` just takes the structure you provide it, and converts it to a string in valid JSON (if possible).

What you need to do is instead of using `array_push($row, $width)`, do something along the lines of: `$row['width'] = $width;`, and the same for `$height`. Then your `$row` array will have the key `width` that points to the variable `$width`, and json_encode will encode it appropriately.