# PHP getimagesize not working on external links

Tags: php, fopen, mod-security, getimagesize, safe-mode

I have some issues on my server in running **getimagesize** on remote url images.

For example if I run this code on my local server it works fine and returns OK:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://inspiring-photography.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Culla-bay-rock-formations-Isle-of-Uist.jpg';
$pic_size = getimagesize($file);
if (empty($pic_size))
{
    die('FALSE');
}
die('OK');

?>
```

But if I run the same code on my server I cannot make it work properly. Can you help in determining which settings shall I ask to enable?

I think some of these may be involved:

1. mod_security
2. safe_mode
3. allow_url_fopen

Can you help me in determining the right configuration to get this solved?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, what? *my server I cannot make it work properly* The server probably blocks accesses to other websites. You should enable error reporting in order to show us a real error message.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: sounds like the manual was either not read, not understood, or not followed to the letter.

Comment: @A.L I have enabled error_reporting, but I don't get any error, getimagesize doesn't return any error.

Comment: @PedroLobito I have enabled error_reporting, but I don't get any error, getimagesize doesn't return any error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`allow_url_fopen`  is  **off**. Either enable it on your `php.ini`, or use `curl` to get the image:

```
function getImg($url){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}

$url = "http://inspiring-photography.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Culla-bay-rock-formations-Isle-of-Uist.jpg";
$raw = getImg($url);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($raw);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
echo $width." x ".$height;
```

[SRC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635991/797495)

Comment: Thank you very much @Pedro Lobito for your help, much appreciated.

As stated above allow_url_fopen is enabled, anyway my help desk was able to solve by disabling safe_mode and disable Apache mod_security as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn `allow_url_fopen` on in your `php.ini` file in order to allow it to access resources that are not local.

This is specified in the official document of [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) in the description of the `filename` parameter.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled, anyway my help desk was able to solve by disabling safe_mode and disable Apache mod_security as well.